# Create json of all files in a directory using Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, webpack, bundler

I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── assets
│   └── sprite1.png
│   └── sprite2.png
│   └── sprite3.png
├── dist
│   ├── bundle.js
│   └── index.html
├── src
│   └── main.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

I am wanting to to generate a `manifest.json` file in `dist/` on build that will look something like this:

```json
{
    "sprite1": "../assets/sprite1.png",
    "sprite2": "../assets/sprite2.png",
    "sprite3": "../assets/sprite3.png"
}
```

I want to do this by using webpack to scan all the file paths in `assets/`, so that all I have to do is drag-and-drop `.png` files in `assets/` and they will automatically be written to the manifest, which other parts of my app will use to load in assets.

Is this possible? Is there a better way to do it than using webpack?

Comment: Sounds like you might want to try out `webpack-manifest-plugin`.

Comment: I've tried that, but it looks like that only creates manifests of items in the output directory. It kept making the values be the `index.html`,`bundle.js` files from `dist/`, when I need it to be the `.png` files inside of `assets/`

Comment: `ManifestPlugin` takes a `filter` function option that might help here. Are you getting all the pngs as well in the generated manifest? Posting your webpack config might help.